# Cannot start any server instance

Tags: server, apache2, mysql

I'm trying to start both a mysql server and a apache2 server for a work project I've been on for about month, never had any problem with it until recently.. One morning, I tried starting my servers and everything seemed to work fine until my pc CPU started going up extremely fast. When i looked at the different processes, i saw bunch of init process (like 7 process), multiple bash processes, multiple apache2 process, and few ruby ones. Since then, everytime I open a ubuntu terminal, the initial prompt doesn't even show up, and if I manage to start a server, the same problem happens. I don't know what's happening, and I definitely don't understand the problem or the cause. I've asked a good coworker for help and we haven't find anything. I'm starting to get really desperate because I got something to do before friday, and i can't even get the project to work!

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 Version 1909 x64, with Ubuntu Subsystem linux 18.04, the only thing I get helping me understand what's going on are the different processes it creates, I just realized whenever I open Ubuntu it create like 4-5 init and 4-5 bash processes. If you could walk me through the recovery console thing or runlevel 1, It would be of great help!

Comment: Windows Subsystem for Linux is not designed to provide a complete Ubuntu environment. Virtualization is the professionally accepted solution for this kind of installation.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;  for review.  It sounds like you are trying to run multiple instances.  How are you terminating the old Ubuntu sessions?  View my profile, Network profile for our FAQ page that has information on terminating activities.